# SQL query to select data from three tables and a serialised column

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

I have three tables:

**Sale**

```
sale_id    buyer    grand_total   payment_status
  42        1         1000        [{"vendor":"3","status":"paid"}] 
  43        1         2000        [{"vendor":"1","status":"paid"}]
  44        1         6000        [{"vendor":"3","status":"paid"}]
  45        2         3000        [{"vendor":"3","status":"paid"}]
  46        8         3000        [{"vendor":"3","status":"paid"}]
  47        8         5000        [{"vendor":"1","status":"paid"}]
```

**User**

```
user_id                      
  1     
  2
  8
```

**Vendor**

```
vendor_id  
  1      
  2         
  3                 
  46
```

I would to have a query that will select all the users that bought something from all a specific vendor.

For example. How can I have all the users the had made a purchase from the vendor_id 3? And if the user had made more than one purchase, how can I have the total amount purchased?

Comment: What is the type of `payment_status`?  And what is "user" connected to?

Comment: @GordonLinoff JSON

Comment: The issue is with the design of the database. Especially since the data serialised is important information such as foreign keys for other tables. Meaning in the model you would need to do a lot more leg work that if you actually kept to a dbrm style

Answer (score 2):

In MySQL 5.7.9 and later:

```
SELECT buyer, SUM(grand_total) AS total 
FROM sale 
WHERE payment_status->"$[0].vendor" = 3
```

[Docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-search-functions.html#operator_json-column-path)

Comment: Good answer, also should check *Indexing a Generated Column to Provide a JSON Column Index* at https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-secondary-indexes.html

Comment: and how about using MySQL 5.6.x?

Comment: MySQL supports JSON column type from 5.7.8 so if you have server with less version you have good answer above

Answer (score 1):

Something like this could work, although as previously mentioned, you should adjust your table structure to include vendor as separate column:

`SELECT * FROM`sale`WHERE`payment_status`= '[{"vendor":"3", "status":"paid"}]';`

Or if your json is more complicated than that, you could use:

`SELECT * FROM`sale`WHERE`payment_status`LIKE '[{"vendor":"3"%';`